# question about sql server (backup)

Tags: sql-server-2005

really I can not get what is back up for ? would you please help me? thanks

Comment: What version/type of sql server?
And are you asking about what is a backup for?

Comment: its like if this question of yours gets closed, you have google for backup.

Comment: I want to know that If I backup a file then can i use it any time or not? and if I change my database , the values that was inserted to that file will  change or not?

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the mdf/ldf files to an off site data storage facility or external harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

Your server, SAN and building burns to the ground.

Your data goes to the great server room in the sky.

Quickly followed by your job.

Discuss.